# curl - Data tested in postman wont work in php code

Tags: php, symfony, curl, symfony-3.4, php-curl

I have an endpoint and API key that I am testing in Postman and I get a response with data. So, setting in Postman is working as it should and my curl response in my PHP code is returning false on dumping curl response and code 200 when triggering API call.

I just implemented an endpoint and API key from my postman headers that I set. I need two parameters: *int* and *customerNumber*. In postman, they are set as raw JSON data.

Can someone figure out what am I doing wrong?

```
  public function call($action, $parameter)
{
    $endpoint = 'https://api.myendpoint.co.uk/full-dinner-serve/la/la/land';
    $apiKey = 'NNOsndosfl14FS45ddgdg1';

    $ch = curl_init();

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'x-api-key: ' . $apiKey;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    $postBody = array (
        'action' => $action,
        'customerNumber' => $parameter
);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postBody));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    return json_decode($response, true);
}
```

And then calling it:

```
 public function validate($customerNumber)
{

    $response = $this->call(
        'init',
        $customerNumber
    );

    return $response;
}
```

And in final endpoint:

```
 $response = $this->get('service')->validate(
        $this->data['customer_number']
    );
```

Comment: Make up your mind whether you want to set CURLOPT_HEADER to 0 or true?

Comment: Thnak you. I removed that part. I think that is not an issue. Error remained the same. @CBroe

Comment: _“and my curl respone in my PHP code is returning false”_ - what _exactly_ is returning false? The curl_exec itself? Or maybe probably rather the attempt at decoding whatever was returned, as JSON? Well then check _what_ you are trying to decode as JSON there first of all.

Comment: $response = curl_exec($ch); is returning false. @CBroe :/

Comment: And curl_errno / curl_error say what?

Comment: Request Error:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate @CBroe